# Backward compatible break (MenuItem.getActionView) after upgrading to latest build tools & target SDK

Tags: android

I have an app, which is designed to work in API 10 and above.

Previously I was using the following build environment

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

It works pretty fine.

Recently, I just migrate my app to use the following build environment

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

When I test my app in Gingerbread device, I get `null` action view. Previously, it works perfectly fine in Gingerbread device till Lollipop device.

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Use Sherlock actionbar
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
    this.searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);        
    View actionView = searchMenuItem.getActionView();
```

### menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/collapsible_searchtext"
        android:icon="?attr/actionBarSearchIcon"/>
```

Any idea why upgrading to latest build tools & target SDK will break my previous code? Is there any workaround to overcome this?

Comment: I ran into the same exact issue. For now I'm just going to stick with buildToolsVersion 21.1.2 because it doesn't exhibit this problem. Also, I think that changing only the buildToolsVersion can get it to crash without touching the targetSdkVersion but I didn't throughly test all of these possibilities.

Comment: In order to use the latest build tool and SDK, I'm in the middle of migrating entire SherlockActionBar project to AppCompat, to see whether it is going to solve this problem...